# How to map Lotus *.shb file to e-mail

Tags: c#, lotus

I have *.shb file (probably document link) from Lotus Notes and I need to map it somehow to concrete e-mail and then process it. How can I receive mail from *.shb?

Note: I use C#, but it could be in any language.

Answer (score 0):

> shb is a shortcut that opens a specific document in Windows when double-clicked; executed by the Windows Shell Scrap Object Handler (shscrap.dll). 
>   It's similar to a .LNK file, but not as commonly used; also known as a "Windows Shortcut into a Document."

See here, maybe this thread will provide more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/12/6122832.aspx

So, apparently, the shb file is created when you drag-and-drop a Notes document into a Windows context.

What do you see when you open a shb file in text editor?
If you can see some of the formats like this

**- Link description:**

Application 'MailDb', View 'Inbox', Document 'Doc Subject'

**- db replica ID:**

C125722E:00342CBB

**- View id / Document ID:**

OF38D45BF5:E8F08834-ON852564B5:00129B2C

you could construct URLs that would open in either web browser or Lotus Notes client and open the database > view > document by appending this to your Domino server's url (for web browser) or to "notes://server" (for Notes client) :

/Database/View/Document?OpenDocument

See here for more info on Lotus Domino URL construction rules:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html